# Size of Centralizer of a semisimple matrix over a finite field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let us consider the following matrix in $Mat_4(\mathbb{F}_q)$ $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ The centralizer algebra $Cent(A)$ in $Mat_4(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is given by
$$Cent(A)=\{\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & b_{11} & b_{12} \\ -a_{12} & a_{11} & -b_{12} & b_{11} \\ c_{11} & c_{12} & d_{11} & d_{12}\\ -c_{12} & c_{11} & -d_{12} & d_{11}\end{pmatrix}\mid a_{11},a_{12},b_{11},b_{12},c_{11},c_{12},d_{11},d_{12}\in \mathbb{F}_q\}.$$
Clearly $|Cent(A)|=q^8.$ Let $G:=GL(n,q)$. Note that $A\in G$. Thus $\mathcal{Z}_G(A)=G\cap Cent(A)$ where $\mathcal{Z}_G(A)$ is the centralizer of $A$ in $G$. What I want to know is the following:

**Is there a direct method to compute the size of $\mathcal{Z}_G(A)$**?

We note that $T=\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b  & a\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{F}_q\}$ is abelian (I don't know if that can be used to our advantage). By bruteforce, one can compute the determinant and find restriction on the entries and then compute the size accordingly, but I wanted know if it can be achieved by some other short technique. We mention that there is a well-known formula for the size of the centralizer of an element in $GL(n,q)$ (see (1.6), Page 181, Symmetric and Hall Polynomials - Macdonald). From there it can be easily computed that $|\mathcal{Z}_G(A)|=q^2(q^2-1)(q^4-1).$

Comment: Are you asking in general or just for this specific matrix? If it's the specific one you are asking for the automorphisms of $V_4(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as $\mathbb{F}_q[A]$ module. If $X^2+1$ is irreducible then the module is just $V_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ and its automorphism group is $GL(2,q^2)$ whose order is what you say.

Comment: BTW You have typos in your $Cent(A)$, all the $x_{22}$ should be $x_{11}$

Comment: Yeah sorry for the silly typo! I completely understand what you are saying. But I just wanted to know if it is possible to compute using the Det condition!

Comment: @Riju Again, did you mean in general or just for this specific matrix?

Comment: In this question for the particular matrix that is written.

Comment: I didn't ask in general because I thought it might be rather difficult for a general semisimple matrix $X$ , that is, to compute the |\mathcal{Z}_G(X)| by putting determinant non-zero condition on the matrices of $Cent(X)$. But if it is easy in the general case too, it will be great if you can give me some ideas.

Comment: Can you explain (by adding to the context of the question) why you are so keen to use the determinant criterion for invertibility? It seems to me that the determinant has nothing to do with this sort of question at all: one simply computes the orders of $GL$'s by a straightforward count of the ordered bases.